# How to do math operation in datagridview using c#?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, sql-server-2014

I have problem to do math operation in datagridview like in Ms. Excel, more specific is i want to substract row[2] and row[3] at column Close, and the result i will save in column Up.

//Let's assume that table's index begin from number 1

[image: This is data image]

I will show my code

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection("Server=TSANAARSYANI;Data Source= TSANAARSYANI; Database = dbSaham;Integrated Security = SSPI");
            conn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From hargaRSI", conn);
            da.Fill(ds,"hargaRSI");
            dataGridView2.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["hargaRSI"];
            object value1 = dataGridView2[2, 2].Value;
            object value2 = dataGridView2[3, 2].Value;
            float val1, val2;
            if(float.TryParse(value1.ToString(),out val1)&&float.TryParse(value2.ToString(),out val2))
            {
                dataGridView2[3, 2].Value = val2 - val1;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("cannot substract, invalid inputs.");
            }
            dataGridView2.Visible = true;
        }
```

note: I use sql server, then retrieve the data in datagridview not dataTable

Comment: whats the values you wanted to subtract, you wanted to subtract close column from date column or date column from close column and also why you want to do that calculations within grid, why don't perform those calculations within your datatable and bind them with grid?

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please do not link to data, post it here.

Comment: i want to substract between row [2] and row [1] at column close (ex: 900.00-900.00) , then the result i put in column up

Comment: ok sorry, i will read the rule before asking @MAdeelKhalid

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: i have been checked it @badiparmagi, once again thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just loop through the rows. then you can do your math operations as you want. check this:

```
 private void setResultOnDataGridView()
 {
     //dont calculate anything if source is null
     if (dataGridView1.DataSource == null) return;

     //get row numbers count
     var rowLen = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

     //loop through rows of your GridView
     foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
         //at last row. done
         if (dr.Index + 1 == rowLen) break;

         //get next row. 
         var nextRow = dataGridView1.Rows[dr.Index + 1];

         string col1 = dr.Cells["Close"].Value.ToString();
         string col2 = nextRow.Cells["Close"].Value.ToString();

         float val1=0, val2=0;
         if (float.TryParse(col1, out val1) && float.TryParse(col2, out val2))
         {
             dr.Cells["Up"].Value = val2 - val1;
         }
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
float value1 = float.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
float value2 = float.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
float sub = value2-value1;
dataGridView2.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value = sub.ToString();
```

Comment: thank you for your suggest, i have tried it, it doesn't works well, there's an error message that say, i can't convert cell[3] to string.